# How do I unescape multiple byte character utf8

Tags: string, unicode, utf-8, lua

I want to unescape `"Sch%C3%B6ne"`. I found this `unescape` function online that works in a lot of cases but not this one because it's 2 characters for one, I tested the following code on http://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo

```
teststring = "Sch%C3%B6ne"

function unescape (str)
        str = string.gsub (str, "+", " ")
        str = string.gsub (str, "%%(%x%x)", function(h) return string.char(tonumber(h,16)) end)
        str = string.gsub (str, "\r\n", "\n")
        return str
end

print(unescape(teststring))
```

It prints `SchÃ¶ne` but I want `Schöne`. Any one can help me?

Comment: It's fixed now. Please try again.

Comment: It indeed now also works on the demo site. Do you work for that site that it is fixed now?

Comment: @IvoBeckers - `lhf` is the one on the right in [that photo](http://www.lua.org/authors.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method works fine, it's the online Lua interpreter that doesn't show correct result in this UTF8 example.

You can test it under another interpreter, e.g, [this one](http://www.compileonline.com/execute_lua_online.php).

Comment: The online Lua interpreter is fine but the web page said `charset=iso-8859-1`. It now says `charset=utf-8`.